# Puppet iterating over a given number range with the each funciton

Tags: puppet

I get two integer's passed into a puppet class and I want to loop over resources based on the range of integers between the two. I can't quite figure out the syntax to do so. The best I have is similar to the following:

```
e.g.
$start_int=4
$end_int=15

$end_int.each |$number| { if $number >= $start_int {...} }
```

Is there a better way to loop over a given integer range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an actual array and iterate that. Sadly, the stdlib `range` function will not yet accept actual numbers (at the time of writing this) so you will need to convert to String.

```
range("$start_int", "$end_int").each |$number| { ... }
```

Comment: Both start and end are inclusive in range function.   `ex: range("0", "3") will return: [0,1,2,3]`

Answer (score 1):

Modern Puppet you can simply use the data type directly:

```
Integer[1,10].each |$i| { notice($i) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Today Puppet accepts integers as arguments for range, so the accepted answer could be rephrased to:

```
range($start_int, $end_int).each |$number| { ... }
```

(so the quotes around `$start_int` and `$end_ind` are no longer necessary)